# load cakephp from index.php with parameters

Tags: cakephp

I'm working on an internal project and the tech team is requiring that the scheduled task be pointed to an actual file (index.php) and cannot access from localhost/controller/action.  They are wanting

```
localhost/index.php?parm=&parm=
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add your file in the webfoot folder. You should be able to access this in the browser.

Comment: Trying to access cakephp controller/action from parameters.  index.php parm parm

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** call "scheduled tasks" (cron jobs I assume) by an URL. You simply don't want to expose this kind of functionality to the public.

[Write a shell for it](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) and use command line args instead, this is the proper solution for that task and should be pretty easy to do *if* you followed the best practice "fat model, skinny controller" advice because you can simply reuse the logic there.

Comment: This isn't a public application. This isn't even on the 'internet'  and I can't use any command line.  It has to be a 'file' and I can tack parameters onto the end (ex: index.php?arg=controller&arg2=action).  I can't even access the server.  The tech team has to do all that.  I only provide some php.

I call it a scheduled task because it's on a windows machine(still not my decision).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, then just disable the URL rewriting and you get what you want (index.php?arg=controller&arg2=action). You can run the cakephp shell on a windows system and I still think it is the  right way to do this.

Comment: I agree but it's a limitation of the project. Lots of crazy requirements.  I don't have access to and they won't allow use of console.

Comment: Then simply disable URL rewriting like I said before and you're done. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration-baseurl